# Finding rows for which at least one keywords is partially matched

Tags: r, dplyr, text-mining, tidyverse

I have a data frame df with column `a` with text. I also have a list of words

```
keywords <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

How to find all rows of df where at least one of the `keywords` are contained in `df$a`?

For example if `df$a` is:

```
hj**a**jk
fgfg
re
```

first row will be returned.

I would prefer a solution which makes use of the *dplyr* package

Comment: Try `df[sapply(df$a, function(i)grepl(paste0(keywords, collapse = '|'), i)),]`

Comment: this is what I get: `a<-df[sapply(final_data$customer, function(i) grepl(paste0(Is_med_word, collapse = '|'), i)),]
Error in df[sapply(final_data$customer, function(i) grepl(paste0(Is_med_word,  : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Comment: Then I recommend you share a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) of your data. However, shouldn't you have `final_data[sapply(...)]` instead of `df[sapply(final_data$....)]`

Comment: you are right! Sorry about this

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 `tidyverse` ways. I added an additional entry to your vector in order to check that all keywords would be checked against, not just the first one.

Since you said this is `df$a`, I made a tibble `df`, of which `a` is the only column, just to fit better with `dplyr` operations that are generally data frame based.

```r
library(tidyverse)

a <- c("hj**a**jk", "fgfg", "re", "rec")
df <- tibble(a = a)
keywords <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

The more `dplyr` way is to start with the data frame, and then pipe it into your filtering operation. The problem is that `stringr::str_detect` works oddly here—it expects to be looking for matches along an entire vector, when in this case we want that to happen for each row. Adding `rowwise` lets you do that, and filter `df` for just rows where the value in `a` matches any of the keywords.

```r
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(str_detect(a, keywords) %>% any())
#> Source: local data frame [2 x 1]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   a        
#>   <chr>    
#> 1 hj**a**jk
#> 2 rec
```

This second way was more intuitive for me, but fits less in the `dplyr` way. I mapped over `a`—not the column in `df`, but just the standalone character vector—to check for any matches. Then I used this as my filtering criteria. Normally `dplyr` operations are setup so the value you're piping in is the first argument of the function, generally a data frame. But because I was actually piping in the second argument to `filter`, not the first, I specified `df` for the first argument, and used the shorthand `.` for the second.

```r
a %>%
  map_lgl(~str_detect(., keywords) %>% any()) %>%
  filter(df, .)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   a        
#>   <chr>    
#> 1 hj**a**jk
#> 2 rec
```

Created on 2018-06-04 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation!!